# Fedora Linux VirtualBox

Tags: fedora, sudo, virtualbox, repository

I am new to Linux and have tried to install VirtualBox on Fedora 17 (I have a 32 bit computer) but I keep bumping into errors.

At first I couldn't open any link because it said it could not establish a secure connection so I reinstalled Fedora and now I only get this error sometimes. Still when I use the terminal to try to install VirtualBox it says that it cannot retrieve `metalink` for `repository:fedora` and now it said that my username is not in the `sudoers` file.

I searched a lot on YouTube and Google but when I find a possible answer it's not complete and I don't have experience or it just generates more errors.

- One of the things I tried is

  ```bsh
  wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/fedora/virtualbox.repo -P /etc/yum.repos.d/
  ```

  but I don't have `wget`.
- The next approach

  ```
  su -c "usermod -g wheel username"
  ```

  doesn't work because of the metalink problem.
- The same problem with

  ```
  yum install sudo -y
  ```

  and

  ```
  yum update ca-certificates
  ```

It would be awesome to learn how to install VirtualBox on Fedora so I can complete a course.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedora 17 is not supported anymore, so no repos for the base OS and Virtualbox are around anymore. I would suggest you not spend any more time trying to get a distro that was end of life in 2013 to work.

You might be better off using the 32-bit version of CentOS 7 ([ISOs here](http://isoredirect.centos.org/altarch/7/isos/i386/)), which is more likely to work, and it’s based on something more recent.

I just checked, though, and there aren’t 32-bit versions of Virtualbox for CentOS7 either.  You could use the built in KVM virtualization, assuming whatever ancient hardware you are using has virtualization available in the CPU.

Comment: Thank you for the time. Would it work if I use Ubuntu (the computer initially had Windows Vista) or should I risk creating a partition on my good 64 bit computer to install a Linux over there so I can install VirtualBox in there without hitting the Windows firewall

Comment: @AltfelSf3me can’t you just run virtualbox on your windows computer?

Comment: Also, are you sure your 32-bit computer really is only 32-bit?  If it ran Vista it’s possible it has a x86_64 cpu.

Comment: I recently installed Mageia on a 32-bit machine because it seems there won't be a 32-bit centos8 and Fedora dropped 32-bits even earlier. Virtualbox is available in the repos so it might be an option.